# How to capture logger.error messages when unit-test Controller with MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, logging, mockito

I have a `Spring Boot` app and I need to verify that whenever a request failed (different from `200`) system logs the status code and message. So far, I cannot find a way to verify `logger`. Is there any way to do it with `Mockito`?

`MyControllerTest` code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
public class MyControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate localRestTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        given(localRestTemplate.getForEntity("/test", String.class))
        .willReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("Unsupported media type", HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE));

        mockMvc.perform(get(MY_URL))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

`MyController` code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/url")
public class MyController {

    protected final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

    private final RestTemplate localRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(RestTemplate localRestTemplate) {
        this.localRestTemplate = localRestTemplate;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "-")
    @GetMapping(path="/report")
    public void getReport() {
        try {
            localRestTemplate
                    .getForEntity("/test", String.class);
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            logger.error("Couldn't trigger report generation!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I made research and one of the possible solutions would be through `Spy` or through changing modifiers to `public`. Both solutions are not applicable to my current configuration.

Is there anything else I miss that can help me verify `logger` content or, at least, if `logger` was called?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30703932/8629960), but be aware that this will change the entire class

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650222/8547799

Comment: @Tns sibling but not duplicate because I also want to have the correct `Controller` behavior which more as sibling/extension to the question you mentioned. I have a [correlated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401388/how-to-enforce-mockitojunitrunner-fail-without-basic-http-authentication).